# Asterisk gdb how to debug Crash with gdb and asterisk 11.5.1 but Still Core Dunp not generated why?

Tags: gdb, segmentation-fault, asterisk, coredump

=========================
[root@officekam asterisk-11.5.1]# df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2             143G   69G   67G  51% /
/dev/sda1              97M   44M   49M  48% /boot
tmpfs                1008M     0 1008M   0% /dev/shm

==============

## Exeplain each Step.

/etc/asterisk/asterisk.conf
    ----
    directories
    astetcdir => /etc/asterisk
    astmoddir => /usr/lib/asterisk/modules
    astvarlibdir => /var/lib/asterisk
    astdbdir => /var/lib/asterisk
    astkeydir => /var/lib/asterisk
    astdatadir => /var/lib/asterisk
    astagidir => /var/lib/asterisk/agi-bin
    astspooldir => /var/spool/asterisk
    astrundir => /var/run/asterisk
    astlogdir => /var/log/asterisk

```
[options]
;verbose = 3
;debug = 3
;alwaysfork = yes               ; Same as -F at startup.
;nofork = yes                   ; Same as -f at startup.
;quiet = yes                    ; Same as -q at startup.
;timestamp = yes                ; Same as -T at startup.
;execincludes = yes             ; Support #exec in config files.
;console = yes                  ; Run as console (same as -c at startup).
;highpriority = yes             ; Run realtime priority (same as -p at
                                ; startup).
;initcrypto = yes               ; Initialize crypto keys (same as -i at
                                ; startup).
;nocolor = yes                  ; Disable console colors.
;dontwarn = yes                 ; Disable some warnings.
**dumpcore = yes**                  ; Dump core on crash (same as -g at startup).
```

======================
my System:
/usr/src/asterisk-11.5.1/:
i run asterisk with : asterisk -U asterisk -vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvgc -dddddddddd

Note : 
gdb is install 
ulimit -U unlimit .

But Core file not geneated .
So how use $gdb corefile

=======other setting ========

**#DAEMON_COREFILE_LIMIT="unlimited" has been added.
    DAEMON_COREFILE_LIMIT="unlimited"**

=============================

```
**# /etc/profile**

# System wide environment and startup programs, for login setup
# Functions and aliases go in /etc/bashrc

# It's NOT good idea to change this file unless you know what you
# are doing. Much better way is to create custom.sh shell script in
# /etc/profile.d/ to make custom changes to environment. This will
# prevent need for merging in future updates.
```

## **ulimit -c unlimited >/dev/null 2>&1**

**

```
# Controls whether core dumps will append the PID to the core filename.
# Useful for debugging multi-threaded applications.
kernel.core_uses_pid = 1

**
===================
kernel.core_pattern = '/tmp/core_dump/core'
===================
**lrwxrwxrwx  1 asterisk asterisk 0 Dec 24 11:44 cwd -> /usr/src/asterisk/asterisk-11.5.1**
-r--------  1 asterisk asterisk 0 Dec 24 11:44 environ
lrwxrwxrwx  1 asterisk asterisk 0 Dec 24 11:44 exe -> /usr/sbin/asterisk
======================================
```

Answer (score 0):

You need

1) compile asterisk with debug symbols

2) in /etc/asterisk/asterisk.conf enable core dump.

Check more info at  [voip-info asterisk debugging page](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+debugging)